# Are photos on Facebook servers stored with the geotagging metadata in their EXIF headers?

Tags: facebook, geolocation

If i download photo from Facebook, will i be able to read its geotagging metadata, or Facebook just parse the uploaded photo, record all EXIF headers into the database (to show the camera model somewhere or to provide them to law enforcement agencies, for example), and then removes them for security reasons?

Comment: Quick question- why don't you download a few pictures from Facebook and look at the exif data?

Comment: Hm, maybe because i doesn't use Facebook.

Comment: Facebook does filter out EXIF data before displaying images. https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10201464422674131

Comment: I'd recommend always disabling location services access in photo apps on phones, it saves battery and it'll prevent eventual leaks if you ever upload the image to a site that doesn't filter out that data (or if you sent it via an instant messaging service or a network share).

Answer (score 1):

Most big websites do filter out EXIF and geocache data. If you were to take a picture on your phone with geocache on, and then upload it to a ftp server it would still have the EXIF and geocache data. I'm almost positive facebook keeps a original copy of the photo and then just redistributes a copy of it onto their website with different headers etc. At the end of the day, you will not be able to get the data from a facebook photo.